# MySQL query to get item counts per month - displayed in row for each item

Tags: mysql, select

I have MySQL table like this (there will be more items in real scenario):

| ID | item | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2021-04-01 |
| 2 | a | 2021-04-05 |
| 3 | a | 2021-05-07 |
| 4 | b | 2021-07-09 |

And I want to create a table (the result will be displayed in HTML table) where **each unique item** name will have **one row** and also **counts of the item for every month** of whole year. So the result for the case above will look like:

| item | m1 | m2 | m3 | m4 | m5 | m6 | m7 | m8 | m9 | m10 | m11 | m12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I would be able to do that by 2 separate `SELECT` queries where the second one would probably be in the `for` loop, but I can't figure out the way how to do that in one `SELECT` or one multiselect query, if that is even possible.

I got only that far, then got stucked:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as m, COUNT(item) as c
FROM itemtable 
WHERE YEAR(date)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND item="a" 
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @CaiusJard no, it was just stress I want it in rows. Removed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pivot operation. In MySQL I usually do it via conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT item,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as m1, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as m2, 
  ...
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as m12
FROM itemtable 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' and '2021-12-31'
GROUP BY item
```

To see how it works, remove the SUM/GROUP BY and look at the raw CASE WHEN - it splits the data across 12 columns in a diagonal, and then the sum/group squishes it to one row:

```
   A           A           A B C
   B     ->      B     ->
   C               C
```

I agree with strawberry's observation that this is often best handled in the app code rather than the DB, but as the data is fixed at "month 1" thru "month 12" it does make it relatively easier to do in the DB